# Making a D3 Pie v4 Example - Animate On initial render

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I was working with this starting point: http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799
One thing i cannot figure out is why it doesn't animate at the start. Is there a simple change i could make to make this animate initially?

Normally with the attributes i set them to zero, but i cannot figure out how to get the attrTween to animate initially.

Any suggestions?

Added as a snippet if convenient..

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .append("g")

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "lines");

var width = 500,
    height = 200,
 radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
 .sort(null)
 .value(function(d) {
  return d.value;
 });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
 .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
 .innerRadius(radius * 0.4);

var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
 .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
 .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var key = function(d){ return d.data.label; };

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
 .domain(["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", "elit", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt"])
 .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

function randomData (){
 var labels = color.domain();
 return labels.map(function(label){
  return { label: label, value: Math.random() }
 });
}

change(randomData());

d3.select(".randomize")
 .on("click", function(){
  change(randomData());
 });


function change(data) {

 /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
 var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
  .data(pie(data), key);

 slice.enter()
  .insert("path")
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.label); })
  .attr("class", "slice");

 slice  
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
   this._current = this._current || d;
   var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t) {
    return arc(interpolate(t));
   };
  })

 slice.exit()
  .remove();

 /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

 var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
  .data(pie(data), key);

 text.enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
   return d.data.label;
  });
 
 function midAngle(d){
  return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
 }

 text.transition().duration(1000)
  .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
   this._current = this._current || d;
   var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t) {
    var d2 = interpolate(t);
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
    pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return "translate("+ pos +")";
   };
  })
  .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
   this._current = this._current || d;
   var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t) {
    var d2 = interpolate(t);
    return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
   };
  });

 text.exit()
  .remove();

 /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/

 var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
  .data(pie(data), key);
 
 polyline.enter()
  .append("polyline");

 polyline.transition().duration(1000)
  .attrTween("points", function(d){
   this._current = this._current || d;
   var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t) {
    var d2 = interpolate(t);
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
   };   
  });
 
 polyline.exit()
  .remove();
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

path.slice{
 stroke-width:2px;
}

polyline{
 opacity: .3;
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width: 2px;
 fill: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</style>
<body>
<button class="randomize">randomize</button>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you need to set an initial state for the wedges that is different than their final state in order to view the transition.

On initial load of a the chart, check to see if `this._current` is defined, if not, assign it some initial data with:

```
  if(!this._current) this._current = startSlice; // assign initial data
  else this._current = this._current || d;       // otherwise, continue as before.
```

Where `startSlice` might look like:

```
var startSlice = {
 startAngle: 0,
 endAngle: 0,
 padAngle:0,
 value:0,
 data: {lable:"",value:0}
}
```

Or however else you need it to suit your needs. I've updated only the wedges in the animation below:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .append("g")

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "lines");

var width = 500,
    height = 200,
 radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
 .sort(null)
 .value(function(d) {
  return d.value;
 });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
 .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
 .innerRadius(radius * 0.4);

var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
 .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
 .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var key = function(d){ return d.data.label; };

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
 .domain(["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", "elit", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt"])
 .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

function randomData (){
 var labels = color.domain();
 return labels.map(function(label){
  return { label: label, value: Math.random() }
 });
}

change(randomData());

d3.select(".randomize")
 .on("click", function(){
  change(randomData());
 });


function change(data) {

 /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
  
  var startSlice = {
     startAngle: 0,
     endAngle: 0,
     padAngle:0,
     value:0,
     data: {lable:"",value:0}
  }

  var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
  .data(pie(data), key);

 slice.enter()
  .insert("path")
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.label); })
  .attr("class", "slice");

 slice  
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
   if(!this._current) this._current = startSlice;
      else this._current = this._current || d;
   var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t) {
    return arc(interpolate(t));
   };
  })

 slice.exit()
  .remove();

 /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

 var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
  .data(pie(data), key);

 text.enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
   return d.data.label;
  });
 
 function midAngle(d){
  return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
 }

 text.transition().duration(1000)
  .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
   this._current = this._current || d;
   var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t) {
    var d2 = interpolate(t);
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
    pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return "translate("+ pos +")";
   };
  })
  .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
   this._current = this._current || d;
   var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t) {
    var d2 = interpolate(t);
    return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
   };
  });

 text.exit()
  .remove();

 /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/

 var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
  .data(pie(data), key);
 
 polyline.enter()
  .append("polyline");

 polyline.transition().duration(1000)
  .attrTween("points", function(d){
   this._current = this._current || d;
   var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
   this._current = interpolate(0);
   return function(t) {
    var d2 = interpolate(t);
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
   };   
  });
 
 polyline.exit()
  .remove();
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

path.slice{
 stroke-width:2px;
}

polyline{
 opacity: .3;
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width: 2px;
 fill: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</style>
<body>
<button class="randomize">randomize</button>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

</body>
```